# How to mock startActivity() within try-catch block?

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing

```
fun rateUs(activity: FragmentActivity) {
        val appPackageName = activity.packageName // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
        try {
            activity.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=$appPackageName")))
        } catch (anfe: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            activity.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$appPackageName")))
        }
    }
```

I want to write a test case to check if startActivity performs on Uri.parse("market://details?id=$appPackageName").

```
@Test
    fun rateUs_LaunchGooglePlayStore() {
        // Mock the necessary dependencies and configure them as needed
        val activity = mock(FragmentActivity::class.java)
        val packageName = "com.example.myapp"
        val intent = mock(Intent::class.java)
        val uri = mock(Uri::class.java)

        `when`(activity.packageName).thenReturn(packageName)
        doNothing().`when`(activity).startActivity(any(Intent::class.java))
        `when`(intent.resolveActivity(any(PackageManager::class.java))).thenReturn(ComponentName(packageName, "FakeComponentName"))

        // Invoke the rateUs function
        ViewUtils.rateUs(activity)

        // Verify that startActivity is called with the expected intent
        val argumentCaptor = argumentCaptor<Intent>()
        verify(activity).startActivity(argumentCaptor.capture())
        val capturedIntent = argumentCaptor.firstValue

        assertNotNull(capturedIntent)
        assertEquals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, capturedIntent.action)
        assertEquals(Uri.parse("market://details?id=$packageName"), capturedIntent.data)
    }
```

Test failed:
Expected :android.intent.action.VIEW
Actual   :null
But it is expected to not null, what to modify?